# python discord activities

Tags: python, discord.py

я хочу сделать отслеживание статуса пользователя, но activities возвращает мне пустой кортеж, хотя активность мембера есть (пробовал запускать игру, споти и т.д)

```py
@bot.command()
async def stat(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(member.activities)
```

Также видел, реализацию с срезом `activities[0].name`, но она ничего не возвращает т.к.,он пустой. Буду признателен, если кто-то подскажет

Comment: У вас включены `Intents`?

Comment: Какой же я глупый, огромное спасибо вам, вы мне очень помогли. Видимо нужно улучшать свои навыки чтения документации и гугления. Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, успехов вам

Comment: Я оставил ответ, примите его как решение вашего вопроса

Comment: Вы оставили комментарий, я не могу функционально этого сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включите `Intents`, перейдя по [ссылке](https://discord.com/developers/applications/), во вкладке `Bot`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]